# Why this function return is not returning expected results in Java?

Tags: java

Below is a function which takes int and return int. Within the function I call the function itself and if i==1, I want to go out of my function.

Basically I'm trying to calculate factorial in recursive manner.

Code Snippet

```
static int factorial(int i){
   result = result * i;
   if(i==1){
       return 0;
   }
   factorial(i-1);
   return 1;
}
```

Note - result is an global int variable and is initialize to 1.

Why this function returns 1 instead of 0.
[Note when i==1 then with return statement the pointer should come out of the function]

Please don't post better algorithm for factorial, I'm looking for - why this code is behaving a bit different.

Comment: `result` is defined nowhere

Comment: @azro Note - result is an global int variable and is initialize to 1.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP should spend a couple of weeks learning how to write and debug java.

Comment: Vote to close, student needs to learn better investigative strategies. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example calling `factorial(3)`:

```
int i = factorial(3);
    +--------------------------------------------------+
    |result = result * 3;                              |
    |if (i==1) {                                       |
    |  // not executed                                 |
    |}                                                 |
    |factorial(2);                                     |
    |    +-------------------------------------------+ |
    |    |result = result * 2;                       | |
    |    |if (i==1) {                                | |
    |    |  // not executed                          | |
    |    |}                                          | |
    |    |factorial(1);                              | |
    |    |    +---------------------------------+    | |
    |    |    |result = result * 1;             |    | |
    |    |    |if (i==1) {                      |    | |
    |    |    |  return 0;                      |    | |
    |    |    |// nothing more in factorial(1)  |    | |
    |    |    +---------------------------------+    | |
    |    |// factorial(1) returned 0 (value not used)| |
    |    |return 1;  // factorial(2)                 | |
    |    +-------------------------------------------+ |
    |// factorial(2) returned 1 (value not used)       |
    |return 1;  // factorial(3)                        |
    +--------------------------------------------------+
i = 1; // the value returned by last call
```

`factorial(3)` returns 1!  <sub>recursion was *terminated* by `return 0`, but that value is not being used</sub>

Zero would have been returned if the last two lines were joined to `return factorial(i-1);`

---

<sub>only `factorial(1)` will return 0, e.g. `int i = factorial(1)`</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much , now i  understood where i was going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't even compile as `result` isn't defined.

Then, the method **could** return either `0` or `1`, nothing else regarding the `return` you wrote, so you can't expect to get real values.

---

Then the **real** algorithm

- for `0` or `1`, return `1`
- else return the value multiplied by the `factorial(previous)`

```
static int factorial(int i) {
    if (i <= 1) { // for 0 or 1
        return 1;
    }
    return i * factorial(i - 1);
}
```

Comment: He said that the result is a global variable. He is only curious about the return value of his code snippet. He may be using that global variable to get the factorial.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan which does not matter, OP should not use a global variable in the first place. This is the only correct answer.

Comment: @luk2302 I respect your view about the correct usage ....But thanks to the community , i got my recursion doubt solved.[at least i got a hint]

Answer (score 0):

Because u are not returning 0. Your function will always return 1 which is the returned value of the first call. All the other recursive function calls are being made but not being used to return by the parent function. For example if you call factorial(5) then all the recurring calls (from 4 to 1) would execute and process the "result" variable but you will only get the returned value of factorial(5) which is always going to be 1.

Comment: hii thanks for quick reply....but see if i==1 then with return statement ,isn't function should go out of the function scope

Comment: plzz debug this code ...........u will get an idea what i am trying to say!

Comment: Yes it would but you see the area where you are checking the return value of your function has nothing to do with that last function call. Your main function is only communicating with the first function call i.e., factorial(5) which is not using its child recurring function values as a return value so your main code will never see return 0 only the function call factorial(2) can see that factorial (1) is giving 0

Comment: Your idea behind using the global variable "result" should be to not bother about the returned value in the first place. If you are taking factorial from result variable then no matter what the function is returning, u will always have the required value in results

Comment: so you mean factorial(1) return 0 is only visible to factorial(2) and not the main function ..right?

Comment: Right. That's the whole point of recursion.

Comment: Yay getting result is not the problem instead i am looking for flow of code ...why this function is behaving in a certain way

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.........I think i need a refresher on Recursion ... any good resource to follow?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem with your code is that it is confused about how it wants to return data.

You have a `result` global variable which is supposed to be how this function 'communicates' the answer, but it *also* has a return value. They sound quite different (one is a variable, one is a language construct), but they are used for the same purpose here. Half the time you return, half the time you set `result`, and this leads to your code having the effects you are observing.

The solution is to pick a side. Either use *only* `result` - update the method to have a `void` return value, and do not use the `return x;` statement (only `return;`). Alternatively, get rid of `result` entirely, and communicate using `return`.

> ```
> if(i==1){
>           return 0;
>       }
> ```

Take this line and compare to the very next one:

> ```
> factorial(i-1);
> ```

This line calls the `factorial` function and *throws out whatever it returned* because you don't assign it anywhere. That is why you can't observe that 0 you are returning: Because you ignore it.

It looks to me like you think that `return 0;` somehow sets `result`, or that `result` holds 'whatever the function returned' but this isn't true. They are separate things.

Comment: *"The solution is to pick a side."* - honestly the solution is to not use a global variable to hold arbitrary state, having a `factorial` be `void` smells badly.